# How to change backcolor of a field of a continuous sub-form, if this field is null

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a continuous sub-form with 2 fields **"id_arriv"** and **"id_depart"** in which only one of these is not null and the other one is null depending of the kind of move. I would like if the one of these is null then backcolor change to red. I tried:

```
if Me.id_aariv.value is null then
ME.id_arriv.back color = vbred
```

This works, but change all of the fields of "id_arriv

Comment: Use conditional Formatting in that field. Check [Highlight data with conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/highlight-data-with-conditional-formatting-7f7c0bd4-7c37-421d-adad-a260125c8129)

Answer (score 0):

In design view select your field and click menu Format. There is Conditional Formatting icon. Click on it. Click New Rule and set it as Field Value is equal to vbNull. Select your color and click OK.